# flash on release not working with on rollover

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am stuck on a Movie Clip which i make on rollover effect then put link inside in this movie clip
now the problem is that onrollover work but on release not any solution ??

code m using

```
on(release){
getURL("name.html")
}
```

sample file link

http://escribir.biz/nb1/sample.fla

http://escribir.biz/nb1/sample.swf

the main box have on rollover and on rollout effect and link is in this movie on layer 2 and box in layer 1 
in actual movie there are many boxes like this which have links but when rollover work link on release not work

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a MovieClip and give it a name "button1"
2. Dublicate that MovieClip as many Buttons you want and give names as "button2" "button3" etc
3. Create another MovieClip and give it the name "main" put it in your Layer 1 and add "Main" as an instanceName
4. Inside the "Main" MovieClip add the two Buttons and add "Button1" and "Button2" as an Instancename each
5. Create a Class file for main MovieClip
6. Copy paste the following code as class

or download the examples.zip to see it http://www.comvos.net/downloads/examples.zip

```
    class main extends MovieClip
    {
        function main() { super(); }
        function onLoad()
        {
            this.ControlMyMC();
        }
        function ControlMyMC()
        {
            //Turn OFF the HandCursor of Main MC
            this.useHandCursor = false;

            this.onRollOver = function()
            {
                this["AnimatedBG"].gotoAndPlay(2);
                trace("RollOver Main MC");
            }

            this.onRollOut = function()
            {
                this["AnimatedBG"].gotoAndPlay(21);
                trace("RollOut Main MC");
            }

            var ButtonInstanceNames:Array = [
                                    "Button1",
                                    "Button2"
                                    ];


            for(var i:Number = 0; i < ButtonInstanceNames.length; i++)
            {

                this[ButtonInstanceNames[i]].onEnterFrame = function()
                {
                    if (this.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true))
                    {
                        //ROLL OVER BUTTON
                        if (!this.isRollOver) 
                        { 
                            this.isRollOver = true; 
                            trace("RollOver " + _name);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //ROLL OUT BUTTON
                        if (this.isRollOver) 
                        { 
                            this.isRollOver = false; 
                            trace("RollOut " + _name);
                        }
                    }
                }


                //ON RELEASE ---(if you want to use onPress .... just replace the onMouseUp wit onMouseDown
                this[ButtonInstanceNames[i]].onMouseUp = function()
                {
                    if (this.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true))
                    {
                        switch (_name)
                        {
                            case "Button1": trace("You Clicked on Button 1 ... replace me with --->   this.getURL(\"page1.html\");"); break;
                            case "Button2": trace("You Clicked on Button 2 ... replace me with --->   this.getURL(\"page2.html\");"); break;

                            //example
                            case "Button3": this.getURL("name.html"); break;
                            default: trace("aa"); break;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1st try to create a simple class for your movieclip and put your controls there.

for example:

```
class YourMovieClipClassName extends MovieClip
{
    function YourMovieClipClassName() { super(); }
    function onLoad()
    {
        this.ControlMyMC();
    }
    function ControlMyMC()
    {
        this.onRollOver = function()
        {
            //Do on some
        }
        this.onRollOut = function()
        {
            //Do on some
        }
        this.onPress = function()
        {
            //Do on some
        }
        this.onRelease = function()
        {
            this.getURL("name.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok! In your sample file and in your library you have a MovieClip with name "Symbol 2". 1) Right-Click and then click Properties. 2) Click Advanced button. 3) Click Export For ActionScript and Export in Frame 1. 4) Type in Class the YourMovieClipClassName and click OK. 5) In "Symbol 2" Right-Click again and now click on "Edit Class" 6) In the new opened tab copy and paste the the code above. 7) Make your changes 8) Save that as YourMovieClipClassName.as file 9) Finally Remove yours on(rollOver) and on(rollOut) source code

Comment: Sorry in your sample.fla file you have another issue. You cannot use the button to a button ... for example you mc1 "Symbol 2" works as a button (because you use on roll over and out functions) and inside it you have another two buttons. Give me some time to check it..